# DSum with tempvars returning error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some VBA code that sets a `TempVar`:

```
TempVars!ThisQtr = quarter
TempVars!LastQtr = lastQuarter
TempVars!LastYr = lastYear
TempVars!ThisYr = currentYear
```

Great! I know that it does set it as I have checked multiple times.

**now my problem:**
I'm trying to use this in a query

```
DSum("[SumBase]","CompareUnionQuery","[AU] = '" & [AU] & "' AND [GRP_ID] = " & [GRP_ID] & " AND [ACCOUNT] = '" & [ACCOUNT] & "'" & " AND [Fiscal_Year] = " & [TempVars]![ThisYr] & " AND [QTR]= " & [TempVars]![ThisQtr])
```

which this does work when I change out the `TempVars` with values. Can anyone help me with this?
I have tried to put a single quote around them and that doesn't work.

[image]

this expression does work:

```
DSum("[SumBase]","CompareUnionQuery","[AU] = '" & [AU] & "' AND [GRP_ID] = " & [GRP_ID] & " AND [ACCOUNT] = '" & [ACCOUNT] & "'" & " AND [Fiscal_Year] = 2015 AND [QTR]= '3'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the last pieces of your `DSum` expressions ...

1. `AND [QTR]= '3'")`
2. `AND [QTR]= " & [TempVars]![ThisQtr])`

You reported #1 works and #2 triggers the *"Data type mismatch"* error.  So add single quotes before and after the `TempVar` value ...

```
AND [QTR]= '" & [TempVars]![ThisQtr] & "'")
```